# Redefining types in Rust and calling functions on them

Tags: types, rust

In Go you can do something like this to define a custom type that shadows an existing one:

```
type Header map[string][]string
```

Then you can access a Header type the same way you do a `map[string][]string`.

I tried doing the same with Rust but I'm running into issues:

```
pub type Header = collections::HashMap<String, Vec<String>>;
fn main() {
    let h = Header::new();
}
```

You can call HashMap::new(), [as the docs indicate](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) (accessed December 8, 2014). Why can't I call Header::new()?

Comment: It's worth noting that you also can't impl Header { fn new() -> Header } because: ' cannot associate methods with a type outside the crate the type is defined in; define and implement a trait or new type instead [E0116]' This feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @Doug: it’s purely an alias; `impl Header { … }` is precisely equivalent to `impl HashMap<String, Vec<String>> { … }`. No bug there.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan if it was a proper alias (eg. use foo::Bar as Foo) you could use Foo::new() with no issue. Surely its a bug that this doesn't work?

Comment: @Doug: it is not inherently a bug; it is simply something that behaves differently. It has defined a type alias, that is all.

Comment: (It may not have done what you expected, but that doesn’t make it a bug—the parallel you draw is only a parallel, the two things are very definitely different.)

Answer (score 1):

A `type` alias is purely an alias for the *type*. It doesn’t alias the namespace at all, so you will still need to write `HashMap::new()`.

Comment: I thought I heard some of the core devs saying it was intended to work "at some point", would you have any information?

Comment: I have no further information on the topic. Such a thing would be almost backwards compatible, but not quite (beyond the incompatibility that adding methods can produce, any impl on an alias could stop working on the base type, depending on how it was implemented).